# Automate Repeated LaTex Code

Tags: tables, automation

I have a table that looks like this with codes below that produces it.
However I wanted to create 50 of these tables, off course with the values 
that changes.

[image]

How can I do it without writing the code like 50 times ?

```
---
# Combining rows and columns 
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
- \usepackage{caption}
- \usepackage{multirow}
- \usepackage{setspace}
---

\begin{tabular}{ |p{3cm}||p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|  }
\hline
 start & Jay & Arm & Eem\\
\hline
 X & 10 & 9 & 8 \\
 Y & 3  & 6 & 10 \\
 Z & 1  & 6 & 5  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! `pgfplotstable` allows you to load data files and use their data to typeset tables.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Have you got some csv files with the values or what else?

Answer (score 1):

If the tables are identical, create your own environment. The arguments of the `\newenvironment` macro specifies the name of the environment, what happens when it starts, and what happens when it ends.

```
\documentclass ...
...
\newenvironment{mytable}
{\begin{tabular}{ |p{3cm}||p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|  }
   \hline
   start & Jay & Arm & Eem\\
   \hline}
{\hline
   \end{tabular}}
...
\begin{document}
...
\begin{mytable}
 X & 10 & 9 & 8 \\
 Y & 3  & 6 & 10 \\
 Z & 1  & 6 & 5  \\
\end{mytable}
...
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can we use data frame. with the data frame we can alter with different data and then use it to create the table. Loop through the LaTex code and the data frame to create the same table with different results.

Answer (score 1):

Odd question since you are clearly using Rmarkdown. Of course, then you can take advantage of markdown simplicity to make the tables manually, and of course, you can use use a R funtion as `kable` ok knitr package or `xtable` of the xtable package to load automatically R data frame as latex tables (you can also do that with packages `stargazer`, `Hmisc`, etc. but these two are more than enough, imho).

> [image: mwe]

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r,echo=F}
df<- data.frame(start=c("X","Y","Z"),Jay=c(10,30,1),Arm=c(9,6,6),Eem=c(8,5,10))
```

:With Rmarkdown

|start  |  Jay|  Arm|  Eem|
|:------|----:|----:|----:|
|X      |   10|    9|    8|
|Y      |    3|    6|   10|
|Z      |    1|    6|    5| 


:With Rmarkdown (simplest)

start       Jay   Arm    Eem
-------  ------ ----- ------
X            10     9      8 
Y             3     6     10 
Z             1     6      5  


```{r,echo=F}
knitr::kable(df,caption="with knitr")
```

\belowcaptionskip1em
```{r,echo=F,results='asis',message=FALSE}
require(xtable)
options(xtable.comment = F)
print(xtable(df,digits=0, caption="with xtable"),include.rownames = F,booktabs=T, caption.placement="top")
```
````

Answer (score 1):

You didn't give enough information.

In case you have 50 `csv` files with your data, you can use a `\foreach` with a `\csvreader`.

My example has only three files for convenience, but you can have as many as you like.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{caption}

% filecontents is only to create the files, you don't need the following code if you already have them
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{file1.csv}
start, Jay, Arm, Eem
 X, 10, 9, 8 
 Y, 3, 6, 10 
 Z, 1, 6, 5
\end{filecontents*} 
\begin{filecontents*}{file2.csv}
start2, Barbara, Bea, Bill
 X, 2, 2, 2 
 Y, 2, 2, 2 
 Z, 2, 2, 2
\end{filecontents*} 
\begin{filecontents*}{file3.csv}
start3, Carla, Chuck, Colin
 X, 3, 3, 3 
 Y, 3, 3, 3 
 Z, 3, 3, 3
\end{filecontents*} 
\begin{document}
\foreach \ind in {1,...,3}% you can have 50 instead of 3 here
{\begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
    \caption{A table from \texttt{file\ind.csv}}
    \csvreader[tabular=cccc,
        head=false,
        table head=\toprule,
        late after line=\\,
        late after first line=\\\midrule,
        table foot=\bottomrule,
        ]{file\ind.csv}{}{\csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii & \csvcoliv}
\end{table}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If the files are not numbered as I supposed in my MWE, you can put the file name list in the `\foreach` like this:

```
\foreach \myfile in {pippo,pluto,paperino}% put the list or your files here
{\begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
    \caption{A table from \texttt{\myfile.csv}}
    \csvreader[tabular=cccc,
        head=false,
        table head=\toprule,
        late after line=\\,
        late after first line=\\\midrule,
        table foot=\bottomrule,
        ]{\myfile.csv}{}{\csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii & \csvcoliv}
\end{table}}
```

The code could also be changed to adapt your needs in case your files don't have the headings or so on.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to TeX-SE !

I would suggest you two methods :

- You can create a template table and save it. So that, each time that you want to make a table, just copy and paste the empty table and insert the desired values.
- If there are some calculations to do and you have the possibility to use Excel,take a look at [Excel2LaTeX](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/support/excel2latex). It is simple yet useful.

There is almost certainly a way to make some automation program (with dialog boxes for example) and it'll be great if someone came up with an easy way to do this but depending on your needs/knowledge you'll choose which method suits you the best.

Comment: Reasonable suggestion however .xla is often a security / compatability  issue or restriction (I and many others can not run them, at all) the simplest way is to fill cells and either export as csv or simlpy formatted plain TeX(t) using extra columns for "&" and "\\" (that would suit your first suggestion of cut and paste)